# CRUD operation authentication for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework3

I'm using zend 3 framework and mongodb. Connected to mongodb database using [mongodb/mongodb](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb) library.

How I can add validation in zend and mongodb so that only authenticated users can perform CRUD operation in mongodb using zend rest apis?

From mongo shell I've added authentication to db using below queries which works fine.

```
use admin;
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
mongo --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"

use test;
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "testUser",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
);

db.auth("testUser", "password");
```

Right now In Zend model I'm using following code which works fine without db authentication.

```
$mongoClient = new \MongoDB\Client();
$collection = $mongoClient->selectDatabase($dbName)->selectCollection($collectionName);
$cursor = $collection->findOne(['_id' => $_id]);
```

Now how I can pass user credentials to `\MongoDB\Client()` to authenticate user before executing above query?

Comment: Hello. What did you tried so far?

Comment: @edigu, I've updated question with my code.

Comment: And it resulted as getting an accurate answer! Congrats!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may initialize the client with credentials as follows:

`$mongoClient = new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://username:password@host1:port');`

Comment: it is working if I'm using admin user but not for test user. Why so?  Also authentication will be requested from third party. Which method I  can use to make sure it's not visible in browser?

Comment: 1. You need to specify the database which test user's roles applies to, similar to : `roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]`

2. These credentials are used within PHP isn't it ? So how come it is visible in the browser ?

Comment: If I use `db.createUser(
  {
    user: "test",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" } ]
  }
);` php code authentication is working fine. Though through mongo shell authentication is not working db.auth('test', 'password')

Comment: mongo --port 27017 -u "test" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" is working fine for test db.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Regarding authentication third parties will be making ajax request will user/pass on their website. So params will be visible. How do you encrypt or do something similar for security?

Comment: May be this has info you are looking for https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/